# How to write the derivative of $V(t) = 2t(1-t)$ as a limit (using first principles).

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I'm trying to find the correct way to write the derivative of $V(t) = 2t(1-t)$ as a limit. i.e.

$f'(x) = \lim{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)} {h}$

When I put the function into the equation I end up with $\frac{0}{h}$ but but online calculators are giving me different answers.

Cheers

EDIT: I tried my best to follow the above formula but I don't really understand which values I'm supposed to put in. This is the formula. I came up with

$$
V'(t) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(2t - 2t + h)^2 - (2t - 2t)^2}{h} = \frac{0}{h}
$$

Comment: You'd better first tell us how you end up with $0/h$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $$\frac{V(t+h)-V(t)}{h}=\frac{2(t+h)-2(t+h)^2-2t+2t^2}{h}$$
simplify and compute the limit for $h$ tends to zero.
It gives
$$\frac{2t+2h-2t^2-4th-2h^2-2t+2t^2}{h}$$

Comment: What is the value of v in the first line?

Comment: It denotes your function $v(t)$

Comment: What's being done in the first step to get the second line that's the part I'm stuck on?

Comment: @C.Deighton Are you confused about the function notation? We are plugging in the value $t+h$ into your function $V$. Since $V(x) = 2x(1-x)$ for every $x$, we find that $V(t+h) = 2(t+h)(1-(t+h)) = 2(t+h) - 2(t+h)^2$.

Comment: We then subtract $V(t)$ in the numerator.

Comment: @Sambo Yeah that what was exactly what I was confused about, thank you so much.

Comment: @C.Deighton No problem! Function notation is one of those things that we end up taking for granted; we forget that it's not so obvious at first.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

It's

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{2(t+h)(1-(t+h))-2t(1-t)}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{2h-4ht-2h^2}{h}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\require{cancel]}V'(t):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2(t+h)(1-(t+h))-2t(1-t)}h=$$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cancel{2t}-\cancel{2t^2}-2th+2h-2ht-2h^2-\cancel{2t}+\cancel{2t^2}}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(2-4t)\cancel h-2h^{\cancel2}}{\cancel h}=2-4t$$

Answer (score 0):

The difference quotient is $\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\dfrac{2(t+h)(1-(t+h))-2t(1-2t)}h=\dfrac {2h(1-h-2t)}h=2(1-h-2t)\to2-4t$.

This matches what we get if we just take the derivative:   $f'(t)=2(1-t)+2t(-1)=2-4t$.